# How to call a WCF service from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf, soap

I'm trying to call a WCF service from an ajax call with jQuery.
I manage to call the WCF from SOAP-UI and from Excel/VBA.
My problem comes from the OPTIONS request that's sent and no POST follows:

- if I set URL to `http://mywcf/service.svc`, OPTIONS is sent and I get a `400 Bad Request` status and POST request is not sent. In this case, there's missing `HTTP/1.1` in header (comparing with SOAP-UI headers).
- if I set URL to `http://mywcf/service.svc HTTP/1.1`, OPTIONS is sent and I get a `200 OK` status but POST request is not sent. In this case, `HTTP/1.1` seems to be interpreted as a filename.

Can someone tell me how to call a POST action on a WCF from javascript and to add `HTTP/1.1` header without corrupting service URL?

Here is a extract from my ajax call:

```
var soapData = ''
        +'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mic="http://microsoft.wcf.documentation">'
        +'    <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsrm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702">'
        +'        <wsrm:Sequence>'
        +'            <wsrm:Identifier>s:Sender a:ActionNotSupported</wsrm:Identifier>'
        +'            <wsrm:MessageNumber>1</wsrm:MessageNumber>'
        +'        </wsrm:Sequence>'
        +'        <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence</wsa:Action>'
        +'        <wsa:ReplyTo>'
        +'            <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>'
        +'        </wsa:ReplyTo>'
        +'        <wsa:MessageID>uuid:'+ MsgUid +'</wsa:MessageID>'
        +'        <wsa:To>'+ Url +'</wsa:To>'
        +'    </soap:Header>'
        +'    <soap:Body xmlns:wsrm="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm">'
        +'        <wsrm:CreateSequence>'
        +'            <wsrm:AcksTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">'
        +'                <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>'
        +'            </wsrm:AcksTo>'
        +'            <wsrm:Offer>'
        +'                <wsrm:Identifier>urn:soapui:'+ SeqUid +'</wsrm:Identifier>'
        +'            </wsrm:Offer>'
        +'        </wsrm:CreateSequence>'
        +'    </soap:Body>'
        +'</soap:Envelope>';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mywcf/service.svc', // with or without +' HTTP/1.1'
    data: soapData,
    contentType: 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'xml'
});
```

Values in my WCF `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: One obvious issue is the url in your call. You need to include the WCF method name in the url

Comment: @Sparrow I manage to call the WCF from VBA and SOAP-UI without setting the method name. When I add a method name in my ajax call, it seems to be interpreted as a filename. I don't think it's a solution.

Comment: May the down vote explain their choice, thanks.

Comment: Then perhaps you have not setup the wcf properly in your config file. Are you using Visual studio? If yes, then I think you should use the 'WCF Test Client' tool and check out how it makes the call. That would be the starting point.

Comment: @Sparrow I don't really have a right on WCF development. As I can call WCF via VBA and SOAP-UI, I believe it's possible to do it with an AJAX call too even with OPTIONS preflight. 'WCF Test Client' fails on calling my web method but it's not very verbose so I don't know what happens.

Comment: You certainly should be able to WCF services using ajax, provided that the  http calls in your WCF services are allowed. The power of WCF is that you can define the communication protocols and the interfaces for the calls. I have a feeling that the root of your problem is in the web config file. technically, you have to define which method in the service you are calling and your ajax call is not defining that. If your VBA code can make the call, then you have some weird configuration that defines the target method, which is not according to standard best practices.

Comment: Usually, a service (.svc file) has multiple web service methods and your call to the service should define the target method, so in most apps, the target method name is part of the URL. I see a strange code in your SOAP that define the 'action' and 'reply to'. perhaps your service uses those fields to define the service method. I'm not sure what the 'Reply To' is for. Can that be the issue?

Comment: I generated 'action' and 'replyTo' elements with SOAP-UI, they are needed for WS-Addressing. So I copied them into my soap enveloppe for the AJAX call. On the other side, setting method name in the URL give me the same `400 Bad Request` status.

Comment: &sinsedrix you might get the answer here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-JSON-call-to-ASP.Net-WCF-Service-using-jQuery-and-Javascript.aspx

Answer (score 3):

To consume a web service using jQuery, that is to make a call to the WCF service, you either use jQuery.ajax() or jQuery.getJSON(). In this article I used the jQuery.ajax()method.

To set the request, first define a variable. This will be helpful when you are calling multiple methods and creating a different js file to call the WCF service.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Type;
    var Url;
    var Data;
    var ContentType;
    var DataType;
    var ProcessData;
```

The following function initializes variables which are defined above to make a call to the service.

```
function WCFJSON() {
    var userid = "1";
    Type = "POST";
    Url = "Service.svc/GetUser";
    Data = '{"Id": "' + userid + '"}';
    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    DataType = "json"; varProcessData = true; 
    CallService();
}
```

The CallService function sends requests to the service by setting data in $.ajax.

```
// Function to call WCF  Service       
function CallService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        success: function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
}

function ServiceFailed(result) {
    alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
    Type = null;
    varUrl = null;
    Data = null; 
    ContentType = null;
    DataType = null;
    ProcessData = null;
}
```

Note: The following code checks the result.GetUserResult statement, so your result object gets the property your service method name + Result. Otherwise, it will give an error like object not found in Javascript.

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
    if (DataType == "json") {
        resultObject = result.GetUserResult;

        for (i = 0; i < resultObject.length; i++) {
            alert(resultObject[i]);
        }

    }

}

function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);

    if (xhr.responseText) {
        var err = xhr.responseText;
        if (err)
            error(err);
        else
            error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
    }

    return;
}

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        WCFJSON();
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add webHttpBinding endpoint

```
    <services>
  <service name="Contract">
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="IContract" bindingConfiguration="ActionsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ActionrestfulBehavior"/>
  </service>
```

then call the endpoint from ajax as post or get, see below example :

```
    var data = JSON.stringify({
    param1: val1,
    param2: val2
});
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mywcf/service.svc/json/FunctionName",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true
}).then(function (rsutlt) {

}).fail(function (fail) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your global.asax.cs, and remove customHeaders from your web config.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

    }
```

Also you need remove OPTIONSVerbHandler for enabling cors.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```