# Request in ajax return 500 internal Server Error but in browser it work fine also in SOAPUI

Tags: ajax, iis, soap, request, http-status-code-500

We have migrated a webapp, it was before installed in apache now in IIS.

I do a request to a soap service from my webapp instaled in IIS to another machine that have the soap service, this service is deployed in apache. I use a proxy in IIS. When the request is done in Ajax it return 500 Internal Server Error but if I copy and pate the url request in the browser it return that the sevice is active and in SOAPUI also return the expected.

It is the code structure hat i use to text the request out the main aplication.

Thank you in advance

```
var webServiceURL = 'https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/proxy/proxy.ashx?http://xxx.xxxx.xxx.xx/Servicie/services/Service';
var soapMessage = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' >soapenv:Header*</soapenv:Header> soapenv:Body</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>" function CallService() { $.ajax({ url: webServiceURL, type: "POST", dataType: "xml", data: soapMessage, processData: false, contentType: "text/xml; charset="utf-8"", success: OnSuccess, error: OnError });
function CallService()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceURL, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml", 
        data: soapMessage, 
        processData: false,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: OnSuccess, 
        error: OnError
    });

    return false;
}

function OnSuccess(data, status)
{
    alert(data.d);
}

function OnError(request, status, error)
{
    alert('error');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
});
```

Comment: If you can use the browser and SOAPUI to access the service normally, it should not be a service problem. I think it may be a problem with your Ajax. You can refer to this link. The link contains how to use Ajax to request a WCF service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763360/how-to-call-a-wcf-service-from-javascript

Comment: Thank you for the link, but this doesn't solve my problem still same error

Comment: I suggest you use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Hi thank  you for your link, I have realised that in the step ISAPI and CGI Restrictions where i need deney the Active Server Pages, I don't have any Active Service Pages, could that be the problem?

Comment: It is possible. I think if there is no problem with the service, it may be that there is a problem with your ajax request. Is your SOAP message correct?

Comment: Yes my message is correct, I can acces it by SOAPUI, buy  it is only when Ido teh request by ajax. also before the app that we use was instaled in a tomcat now we have migrate to IIS. thank you for your help :)